# Cocoa Drawing Clickable Text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, text, drawing, clickable

I am trying to draw some text that is clickable.
I am trying not to use NSButton as my text is being drawn in drawRect and using NSButton in a drawRect makes it add the subview on top of itself unless you go through and remove all subviews on each call of drawRect.

I tried creating a NSButton and instead of adding it as a subview I am calling [myBtn.cell drawTitle: withFrame: inView:] which draws the text, but it is not clickable.

Is there a way to draw text (in a way like using drawInRect) but where I can also have the text be clickable?

If not, what would you recommend? Using a standard NSButton and clearing all the subviews each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I've seen this done before is to use an `NSAttributedString`.  The part that's clickable should be changed somehow (ie, have a different `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`) and then attach the `NSURL` to it with the `NSLinkAttributeName`.

If I remember correctly, I believe this is an `NSTextField` subclass that does this:  [`DSClickableURLTextField`](http://www.nightproductions.net/developer.htm#DSClickableURLTextField) / Swift [DSClickableURLTextField](https://github.com/catlan/DSClickableURLTextField) fork

I would recommend *not* drawing the text yourself, because there are lots of things in AppKit that will do this for you.  Why do you need to draw it yourself?

Comment: Main reason for drawing myself is the fact that if you add a subview in a drawRect then you have to clear the subviews on each run of drawRect or you get multiple subviews on top of each other. I guess it comes down to that I probably shouldn't be doing my text/labels in drawRect.... That is probably the "correct" solution....

Comment: @kdbdallas my general rule is that if something else can draw it for you, let it. :)